# Breach through VNC

Tags: security

I accidentally overlooked that I hadn't assigned a password when I set up my VNC server. I had been using it remotely and it never occurred to me that ANYONE could access my PC. I caught the unauthorized user making a purchase to the Walmart website (using someone elses information, not mine) in which I immediately disabled the internet. I want to report the incident to my local authorities but I'd like to at least give a tad more information like the IP address.

Doesn't VNC keep logs of incoming connections? I can't seem to find the VNC logs in Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit. Is there any other logs I can search for this IP address? I remember it started with 41.x.. before it disappeared from the VNC incoming connection notification.

Comment: What VNC server are you using?  There are many, many VNC servers...

Comment: "it never occurred to me that ANYONE could access my PC" - oh my, what a terrific ignorance about how bad people are. Bad news: Not only do they want to access your PC, they are also ORGANIZED. THe world is not a nice and happy place.

Comment: @TomTom Hey man, of course I know. I feel pretty crappy about it, but I just somehow forgot. I don't know how I could forget such an important detail myself.

Comment: But as you can see it's more common than you think. Look at the parashep's link, there's a bunch of users with the same issue as me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Ubuntu, Vino is the default VNC server installed. Assuming that you're using Vino, well, there's in fact an open bug with it at the moment. It [doesn't store any logs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vino/+bug/330310). Kind of silly for this to be an issue with a VNC server, isn't it? Of course, if you're using another VNC server then this doesn't apply to you.

Comment: Oh my goodness this is a horrible coincidence haha. Well, that sucks. I'll just have to forward the information I have for now. Thanks. I'll leave this question open for a bit in case there's another way the IP could have been stored somewhere.

Comment: I was going to add, if there is any other software that logs TCP/IP connections it could be in a log there. I don't believe that Ubuntu comes with one of those installed by default, but it may have changed.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, or I wouldn't be asking about it here. Haha.

Answer (score 0):

Your legal authorities will be able to find out which IP address made a 5900/tcp connexion onto your own with a search warrant to look at your ISP logs.
You are not in charge to keep these connexion logs.

I advise you to turn on your firewall and block 5900/tcp. You'll be surprised by the number of attempts. You might also be lucky and get the one from your attacker.
Hint: he won't use your IP just once like robots: he knows it should work ;).